# Unable to debug protractor scripts using browser.debugger()

Tags: protractor

I use terminal for execution & debugging scripts; Actually I am unable to debug through `browser.debugger()`; but the same is achieved through `browser.pause()`;

I entered below cmd for execution followed by '`repl`' and then tried to enter protractor cmds but it fail to work :(

```
protractor debug protractor-config.js;
```

**Note:** the execution actually pause on breakpoint but unable to debug it like what we do on browser.pause()

Is there a better approach to debug using `browser.debugger();` ?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `failed to work`? What is happening? Thanks.

Comment: when I enter some protractor functions; eg., element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).clear(); it is not clearing the text field in the running page.

Comment: @alecxe but the same function works when I debug using browser.pause()

Comment: @PrashanthSams I do not think, debugger is there for same purpose. You can't perform actions on element using debugger it is only to locate the elements or test your algorithm.

Comment: @PriyanshuShekhar can you please post how to locate elements through debugger(); as 'repl' cmd is not letting me locate elements.

Answer (score 2):

> Protractor's debugger() method works by scheduling a node debug breakpoint on the control flow.

This is the line you are looking for. what this means is when you are entering into `repl` mode from `browser.debugger()` and trying to locate/perform actions on elements, it queues up in the control flow! that is the reason it just shows the queued up tasks.You could check yours if you look closely!

Now if you come out of `repl` mode (ctrl+c) and press `c` the execution resumes and **it executes your action which was queued up first** you can check it

I agree the documentation is not full proof and clear but you can get an idea by reading it first - http://www.protractortest.org/#/debugging

Protactor's debugger uses node's debugger so you should also read about that - https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

If you want to debug your scripts with `repl mode` I would suggest use

- [browser.pause](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=Browser.prototype.pause)   or
- [browser.enterRepl](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=Browser.prototype.enterRepl) - This would be the ideal feature

Note: You could also change the `ports` by just passing the argument

`browser.pause(6767);` --> would start in port **6767**

`brower.enterRepl(4545);` --> would start in port **4545**

Comment: nice answer; but what i really consider about is the real benefit of browser.debugger() in protractor and I am not getting the source anywhere :(

Comment: like, how to debug using browser.debugger();  truth is we don't need the node way of checking algorithm in protractor as that are UI based tests; I have already used pause() feature and it is pretty good. Is there any specific good features in browser.debugger() ?

Comment: I have posted the answer in Gitter, pls do check!

Comment: really thank you for the quick reply; as said in gitter, "debug their scripts by putting breakpoints to know where the issue exists" - to be clear, I'm able to put breakpoints and on execution, the script also stops at specific scheduled point but how to proceed debugging to see where issue exists ? and tats my overall question

Comment: secondly, what kind of debugging we can do through node way in protractor?

Comment: as per the doc, http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=Browser.prototype.debugger I expect it to work but it didn't :(